# Magento 2 run setup:di:compile command on a shared hosting with limited memory_limit (max 512M)

Tags: magento2, memory, setup-di-compile, hosting

I am trying to execute `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` after enabling a custom module created on my **Magento2** store. However, I am using a shared hosting which allows me to `set memory_limit upto 512 MB`.

Due to this compile command fails. How to run Magento 2 commands successfully on shared hosting with limited **memory_limit?**

```
[ym@webcloud1 testbed]$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% < 1 sec 54.0 MiB
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

Suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Increase the memory limit to update .php.ini file

If you have access to your php.ini file or can create one in the root, you can globally increase your allocated memory.

```
;adjust memory limit
memory_limit = 6G
max_execution_time = 36000
max_input_time = 36000
```

If you not want to update .php.ini file then use below command

```
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile
```